# Select a value from a NumberPicker

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a custom `NumberPicker` to display in a `DialogFragment`. So far I've succeeded in getting the picker to display in a dialog fragment and getting it to display the custom strings I want it to. I've also disabled the descendantFocusability so the text is not editable. Here is an overview of the questions I have about NumberPicker behaviour, I'll go more in depth after:

- How does one 'commit' their selection?
- How to return the selected value?

**How does one 'commit' their selection?**

When the dialog appears, I don't see a clear way to 'select' an option (see image below). Looking at native Android selection dialogs, I often see radiobuttons. Is that the way to go? And am I using the wrong UI component to build this?

[image: The current state of my PickerView.]

**How to return the selected value?**

This question is tightly knit with the last one, as not knowing how to commit a selection obviously doesn't help here. Right now I use `NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener` to see if the value changed, however it never fires. Here's how I structured the code:

```
class PlatePickerFragment: DialogFragment() {
    lateinit var listener: NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener
    //I set up the fragment with onCreateDialog here.
}
```

And this is the code I use when I create an instance:

```
val platePicker = PlatePickerFragment()
platePicker.listener = NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener { numberPicker, i1, i2 -> 
    //set what to do on value change here.
}
```

However, this block never gets called.

**TL;DR:** Am I using the right UI component? If I am, how would I implement this in a way that it works? Why does the NumberPicker not have a `cancel/ok` section by default (see image of DatePicker below)? Thanks in advance!

[image: 'Cancel' and 'Ok' buttons on a DatePicker.]

Answer (score 2):

Answer to first part :

This is the ideal way of implementing NumberPicker. One thing you can do
is add an OK button to side to catch selection.See screenshot

[image]

Code for same :

picker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity :

```
 final NumberPicker aNumberPicker = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    aNumberPicker.setMaxValue(12);
    aNumberPicker.setMinValue(1);
    aNumberPicker.setValue(1);
    aNumberPicker.setFocusable(true);
    aNumberPicker.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    aNumberPicker.setOnScrollListener(new NumberPicker.OnScrollListener() {
      @Override
      public void onScrollStateChange(NumberPicker view, int scrollState) {
        value = view.getValue();
      }
    });
    aNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        value = newVal;
      }
    });
TextView ok = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.tv);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // value variable can be used here
            }
        });
```

Declare **value** as global variable.

Answer to the second part of your question :

```
  int hour;
  numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onValueChange(final NumberPicker numberPicker, final int i, final int i1) {
   hour = Integer.valueOf(numberPicker.getDisplayedValues()[numberPicker.getValue()]);

  }
});
```

On clicking of OK button you will have answer in **hour** variable.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This answer doesn't show how to create a picker view with a button as shown in your image, so the first question remains unanswered.

Comment: @JillevdW Check now , i have updated the answer with code for the first image

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of your answer; it is now clear to me that to get the desired behaviour I have to create a layout including the buttons and other features that I wanted. The OnValueChangeListener still doesn't fire for me, but I've found a way around the problem.

Comment: Hi @JillevdW if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: if there is no obligation to do this, please stop leaving the exact same comment every 10 minutes. Thanks for your input, but this answer was not how I solved my problem, and I am waiting for others to leave a supplemental answer. If that doesn't occur, I will write an answer on how to solve the problems detailed in my question.